# Update using EntityFramework Extended

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-extended

I have a List of objects, in this case, lets say its a Dictionary.
I want to update every item in that list and assign it some new values, but when I run it I get the following.

Thoughts?

Error Message:

> ExecuteReader requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

Code:

```
var db = new OrchidCVBReviewEntities();
db.tblRegistrations.Update(reg => 556083 == reg.RegID, r => new tblRegistration { RegID = 556083, PeopleType = 5555);
```

The example on the EF Extended githum looks very similar, so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Example (from [here](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Source/Samples/net45/Tracker.SqlServer.Test/BatchObjectContext.cs)):

```
var db = new TrackerEntities();
        string emailDomain = "@test.com";
        int count = db.Users.Update(
            u => u.EmailAddress.EndsWith(emailDomain),
            u => new User { IsApproved = false, LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now });
```

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using? And what is `loaded`?

Comment: EF 6.1, loaded is a custom dto class, more or less a List of person class that has an id.

Comment: So the `.ForEach()` call is `List.ForEach`? Have you verified that `ForEach` has something to do with this problem, or can it be further narrowed down?

Comment: Stripling, you are correct, it in fact has nothing to do with it, the issue appears to be just doing the update in this manner at all, meaning it has everything to do with my probable improper use of EF.Extended. Thanks for helping me simplify it :-)

Comment: Not having used EF Extended, I may be of limited help, but here's one thought: EF 6.1 support was only added [a couple of weeks ago](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/commit/1f830c609a3e6971fb88f431b30f1e844437f4d3). Did you pull the latest version from GitHub, or might you be using an older version? Either way, there are still some [open issues](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/issues) complaining that EF6.1 support is not working in certain ways. This could just be a bug.